# Compile errors after upgrade to TFS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm getting 2 different compile errors but repeated across several projects in our solution. The solution was upgraded from VS 2010 to VS 2012. Locally the solution builds fine and runs without error.

1. "The type (xxx) is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Blah, blah, blah..., ...'"
2. "The type caught or thrown must be derived from System.Exception"

The second set of errors seem irrelevant as the try catch block "ex" is the issue but not consistently throughout the solution/projects. Its probably a cascading issue resulting from the first error.

Thanks

Comment: So do you have a reference to the assembly mentioned in the error message?

Comment: Yup. Its a new machine too. The old tfs server was shut down

Comment: Sounds like that assembly that you are referencing is not on your TFS build server.

Comment: Yea, the references point to assemblies on other projects in the solution. No external references to the solution. Doesn't seem like we should have to change the build sequence? Everything worked under TFS/VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

For the reference in question, check to make sure you are referencing the csproj (a Project Reference) and not a binary file that may or may not exist on the build server.  I've seen it before where people somehow get a reference to the .dll in the bin\Debug folder, and when you try to build that on another machine where the bin\Debug doesn't exist yet it will of course fail.

Note: There may be a better way, but when I want to inspect my references I right click the project in Solution Explorer and Unload it, then right-click and Edit it and inspect the XML directly.

Comment: All references in question are verified as project references. I even checked the *.proj file xml source too. We are using the default template from TFS but Im not familiar enough with templates to know what to look for.

Comment: Getting closer. Seems I finally got the Diagnostic logging working and its showing that there was a folder missing for the Build project custom actions or such. When the code was migrated over this folder was missed. We added the TFSBuild project copied over, updated the solution name to build etc (we had renamed the upgraded solution after the migration / upgrade.

Comment: Now it seems that there is a workspace that is inaccessible or something so the build process cant create the workspace as its conflicting and stating it already exists etc.


I don't have direct access to TFS server logon so that's also holding me back from solving this issue sooner.

How can I find where this workspace is referenced and how to rename or delete it ?

I had them execute the commands to delete the workspace on the TFS server but it still says it doesn't exist. Not sure where its pulling the workspace name from?

Answer (score 0):

For "The type caught or thrown must be derived from System.Exception", it looks like you have written a user defined exception which does not inherit System.Exception. You can refer the below link for possible solutions

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/457402/The-type-caught-or-thrown-must-be-derived-from-Sys

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We do have several classes in the same as well as other projects that have the same try catch block but don't give any errors.

    using System;
    
    try
    {
    
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       throw ex;
    }